# The type '...' has no constructors defined

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm noticing the compiler error **The type '...' has no constructors defined** generated when I erroneously attempt to instantiate a particlar class.

It lead me to wonder how I would go about writing my own class that would precipitate this message when someone attempted to instantiate it.

So the code below, what do I need to do to `MyClass`?

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        MyClass()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: if you see this error when inheriting from a class (instead of directly instantiating one)  - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857781/inherit-an-abstract-class-without-any-constructor

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This error ([CS0143](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z6fxc01.aspx)) occurs if the class only defines an [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) constructor and you try to instantiate it from another assembly.

```
public class MyClass
{
    internal MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! The key bit of info here was 'instantiate it from another assembly' I was trying the `internal` keyword in the same namespace, then a different namespace, and still nothing. This now makes sense. Cheers!

Comment: What if it was in a namespace with the same name in a different assembly, or can you not do that?

Comment: @James, the caller can indeed reside in a namespace with the same name, but that wouldn't change anything. The constructor would still be `internal`, and the `internal` boundary is the assembly, not the namespace.

Comment: Durp, indeed, my constructor was internal and I didn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Also this error could be cause if you are compiling with Framework 4 or higher and embedding the Interop Types into your managed assembly. To get rid of this error you need to turn off (No embed) the Embedded Interop Types.

Instructions to turn off embedding:

1. On VS2010 Solution Explorer, right click on the Interop Reference that you are using.
2. Select Properties and look for `Embed Interop Types`
3. Change it from **True** to **False**

You can read about Embedded Interop Types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997297%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Pablo

Answer (score 12):

I've managed to reproduce this by:

- Creating a static class in a DLL
- Using `ildasm` to decompile it to IL
- Editing the IL to remove the "abstract" and "sealed" modifiers from the class
- Rebuilding the DLL with `ilasm`
- Compiling a program which tries to create an instance of the class

If you don't remove the abstract/sealed modifiers, the C# compiler recognizes it as a static class and gives a different error message. Of course, you could start off with a "normal" type and just remove the constructors, too.

EDIT: I actually thought I hadn't submitted this, as I saw the "internal" constructor one first. However, I'll leave it now as my version makes the C# compiler *correct* - there's a difference between a type having no *accessible* constructors and genuinely having no constructors :)

Comment: Leave it to Jon Skeet to come up with an obscure repro case :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you would need to make the constructor of the class internal in order to have it throw this exception. I believe you'll also need the class to exist in another assembly.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{ 
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           MyClass mc = new MyClass();
       }
   }
}

namespace DifferentNamespace
{
   class MyClass
   {
      internal MyClass()
      {
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The namespace doesn't do it, though. I believe it must be the assembly.

Comment: @James, thanks for the update. I'll remove that part from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As has been said, you can get [CS0143](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z6fxc01%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) by trying to instantiate a class with an [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) constructor from outside its assembly.

But I believe it's a compiler bug. The error generated should be [CS0122](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha94aebs%28v=VS.100%29):

> 'member' is inaccessible due to its protection level

... which is the error you get if you try to instantiate a class with only a `private` constructor.

`CS0143` used to happen (up to C# 3.0) if you tried to call a constructor for a built-in type like [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but in C# 4.0 that now generates [CS1729](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384029%28v=VS.100%29):

> 'type' does not contain a constructor that takes 'number' arguments.

if you pass an argument

`Double d = new Double(1.25);`

... or no error at all if you don't pass any arguments to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option: the code might be right, but you might work on different projects in different instances of Visual Studio, and therefore you need to build the referenced project first.