# Inherit an abstract class without any constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class

I want to inherit a class from another class, marked as abstract, that not have any constructor defined.

This is my code:

```
// In one assembly (TheMessage.dll), as seen via F12 in VS (from Metadata)
namespace Namespace1 
{
    public abstract class Message
    {
       public string Body { get; set; }
       // some abstract methods here, not shown.
    }
}

// In another assembly (TheUser.dll)
namespace Namespace2
{
    public class MyMessage : Namespace1.Message
    {
         public MyMessage()
         {
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is that on the `public MyMessage()` constructor I get the error

> The type 'Namespace1.Message' has no constructors defined

I saw on MSDN site ([abstract (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) first example) that inheriting an abstract class without constructor is possible. So, anyone know why I get this error?

Note that one can inherit just fine when type is in the same DLL as the Message class and it works as that assembly exposes some other types deriving from `Namespace1.Message` similar to following:

```
// The same assembly  as Message (TheMessage.dll), as seen via F12 in VS (from Metadata)
namespace Namespace3
{
    public class Message : Namespace1.Message
    {
        public Message() {}
        public Message(string to) {}
    }
}
```

---

I've also checked [The type '...' has no constructors defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958358/the-type-has-no-constructors-defined), but it does not speak about inheritance but rather just new-ing up an instance and I clearly have no expectations to directly instantiate an instance of an abstract class.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't have an internal constructor? Is `Message` your own code? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958358/the-type-has-no-constructors-defined). Also, the code you posted isn't valid, as @xxMUROxx has pointed out.

Comment: The last three methods should have the modifier `abstract`

Comment: This isn't the actual code, so it's hard to say what's wrong...

Comment: This error occurs when you try to instantiate class that has internal or private constructor that is not visible to the caller. The code you have posted doesn't include calling code. You probably want to create simple console program and paste the code in your question that anyone can try out to reproduce the error.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth The `Message` class isn't mine. It is from a DLL so I can't modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If none of the instance constructors of the `Message` class are visible to you (typically because they are all `private` and you are outside the class, or they are all `private` or `internal` and you are outside the assembly), you cannot write a class that inherits from `Message`. (Well, you could make two instance constructors which chain each other cyclicly with the `:this(...)` syntax, but that would not be useful).

Note that when you look at the "metadata" (reflection generated pseudo-C# for an assembly you refer), you typically only see the "visible" members, so any `private` or `internal` members will not show up. I think you look at the metadata because we see non-abstract (and non-extern) methods whoses bodies are absent (just a semicolon `;` there instead of a body `{ ... }`).

The source code of your `Message` class will have one or more constructors, each `private` or `internal`, but when seen from outside the assembly, these are "non-existent".

If the source code of a non-static C# class `Message` contains no instance constructors, the compiler will generate one automatically. It will be a `public` parameterless constructor if the class is concrete (i.e. non-`abstratc`), and a `protected` one if the class is abstract.

That means that if the source code looks like this:

```
public abstract class Message
{
  // note: zero non-static constructors here
}
```

it will be compiled exactly as if it had said:

```
public abstract class Message
{
  protected Message()
  {
  }
}
```

and in that case the generated instance constructor is accessible to *all* classes deriving from `Message`.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have an internal constructor (not shown in the code that you posted) and are trying to instantiate the class with the internal constructor from a different assembly.

(The default constructor for a base class is automatically called from a derived class if you don't explicitly specify a base class constructor to call, so it might not be obvious to you that the base class constructor is being called.)

For example, if one assembly contains this class (inside namespace `ClassLibrary1`):

```
public class Base
{
    internal Base()
    {
    }
}
```

And a DIFFERENT assembly does this:

```
class Derived: Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
    }
}
```

You will see the following compile error:

`The type 'ClassLibrary1.Base' has no constructors defined`

Comment: There is another class in the same DLL that inherits the `Message` class. I added the code of this class in question.