# How to override a method when base class has no constructors defined

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to override a method from the Base class which is a third party DLL.

I'm getting an exception:

> the type 'B' has no constructors defined.

Is there a way to override the method in derived class?

Code snippet below.

```
Public Class A : B
{
   Public A()
   {
   }       

   // method to override from Class B
   public override object BaseMethod() 
   {
   }
}
```

---

I've also checked [The type '...' has no constructors defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958358/the-type-has-no-constructors-defined), but it does not speak about inheritance but rather just new-ing up an instance.

[Inherit an abstract class without any constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857781/inherit-an-abstract-class-without-any-constructor) explains that I can't inherit from such class - so looking for some other way to override a method.

Comment: The error-message is self-explanatory!

Comment: Chris......In this scenario Im inheriting from a Class from external assembly .. So that I need to override in my derived class

Comment: Akbari...I understand the class has no constructors but my goal is to override the method

Comment: If there are no constructors exposed by base there is nothing you can do about it and all info from duplicate still applies. Generally hiding constructors is the way to prevent inheritance when sealed is not an option

Comment: Then how can I override the method from that class?

Comment: @KNC, I significantly updated your post presumably aligning with what you asking (and faking in your research). Feel free to roll back that change if disagree (would need to be re-closed as duplicate). It may be good idea to ask *new separate* question about what you actually trying to achieve as the route you pick may not be officially recommended for classes you use.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [Inherit an abstract class without any constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857781/inherit-an-abstract-class-without-any-constructor) you can't derive from class that does not expose constructors. Hiding constructors is often done explicitly as the way to prevent inheritance when `sealed` is not an option. So there is likely good reason why you can't do that for this particular type.

You options:

- modify (or ask for) the DLL to expose constructors
- see if you actually need to derive from that particular class or there is an interface that your code can implement instead
- derive from some other class if one exists (like `C:B`) that also exposed from the DLL but has accessible constructors. Note that if class hierarchy designed carefully no such classes will be available.

Alternatively you can ask authors of the assembly on how to solve your problem in some other way (there is a good chance they have solutions for common scenarios they already thought about).