# Is it possible to inherit class which is not having constructor in assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If constructor is not there in assembly for a class is it possible to inherit in another assembly

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857781/inherit-an-abstract-class-without-any-constructor#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=If%20none%20of%20the%20instance,class%20that%20inherits%20from%20Message%20.

Comment: I agree that if constructor is internal that we cant see in assembly .but when i am trying to access class it is showing does not contain constructor that takes zero arguments .that means in assembly it is not having constructor only right?