# No constructors defined

Tags: c#, class

I have some code base which has is calling the following:

```
SetHazardDataService();

namespace Analytics.Foo.DataServices
{
    class HDB:IDataService
    {
    }
}
```

With a member function declared in another class/file

```
using Analytics.Foo.DataServices

public void MyDataService()
{
   var DbDataSvc = new HDB();
}
```

originally, I see the same definition used elsewhere but with (no idea if that works):

```
protected void MyDataService()
```

I included the `public` method in my class

I'm now trying to recreate that functionality, but I get the following issue:

> The type Analytics.Foo.DataServices.HDB' has no constructors defined

I'm not sure what the issue is - any suggestions for why this is the case. There is no constructor that I can see. Plus I'm not able to see the other code working/but it doesn't give the same issue.

Comment: confused...  is this a partial class?  I don't see any class declaration around the `MyDataService()`  method.

Comment: Please post a more complete version of the source code so we can understand what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Does it matter that `HDB` isn't marked public? I would try adding `public HDB() { }` as at least an empty constructor to see whether it clears up the "no constructors defined" error.

Comment: Are you calling this from the same assembly? The only possible cause of this that I can think of is [*this question*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958358/the-type-has-no-constructors-defined). As other people have said there will always be a default constructor, and if you declare a private constructor you will get a different error (HDB()' is inaccessible due to its protection level).

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a constructor to class HDB, like this:

```
namespace Analytics.Foo.DataServices
{
    class HDB:IDataService
    {
        public HDB()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, if there's no constructor specified, there will be an empty public parameterless one by default