# The type 'Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element' has no constructors defined

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I want to create a class and have it inherit from the `Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element` class

```
public class MyElement : Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element 
{
  //...
}
```

But when I compile the code I get the following error

The type `Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element` has no constructors defined.

Answer (score 4):

The `Element` class is having an internal constructor. You cannot inherit from a class with internal ctor in another assembly. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958405)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that. But you *can* use extension methods to define new methods on the `Element` class - I have had some good results with this in the Revit context. See my blog post here: http://darenatwork.blogspot.ch/2009/12/using-c-extension-methods-to-extend.html

You can't really add any fields to the `Element` class like this, **but** you can use properties that save to either the new storage feature or the older parameters feature of Revit Elements, so if all you want to do is make an `Element` have some nicer interface, this is a way to do it.

Comment: Okay thank you I will try and let you know. let me know your email address :)

Comment: @user3451925, just add a comment to this answer - then everyone else will know the idea works too!