# Instantiating a class with no constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I am trying to use a class that unfortunately does not have a constructor defined.  When I try to create the object C# tells me that there is no predefined constructor. I was told that this class was created in Visual Basic 6 many years ago, and that somehow in VB the constructor was not needed.

Can anyone think of any solutions for this problem.  Maybe a I could declare a new class and inherit the old one.  Then in the new class I could create the constructor.

```
    someClass  myClass= new someClass();
    //Returns an error saying no constructor can be found at all.
```

Comment: `someClass` has constructor. It's just private or protected. You can use Activator to create instance of this type

Comment: Yes, you can inherit from that class, with your own class, it will work if class has protected constructor

Comment: There are several reasons why a class cannot be instantiated. The class can be abstract, static, the constructor can be private... Without knowing more about this particular class, no way to tell.

Comment: have you tried renaming it? maybe the compiler doesn't like the name "myClass" because it isn't actually your class

Comment: Okay I will try creating my own class and inheriting it.  BTW the class isn't myClass in the IDE, it's proprietary information :(

Comment: Why not open it in Visual Studio, press F12 on someClass and show us what Visual Studio tells you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might have an internal constructor. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958358/the-type-has-no-constructors-defined/6958405#6958405). This would mean you won't be able to access the constructor from a different assembly. (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).)

There might be some method in that assembly that instantiates an instance of that class. Try finding a method like that, and call it to get an instance of `someClass`.

Comment: how do you access the internal constructor could you show some example code

Comment: @user3670048 `internal` is like `public`, except you can't access it from another _assembly_. But if you have some `public` method in the original assembly with a return type `someClass` - You can call that method (which _can_ access the constructor) and that method will give you an instance of `someClass`.