# Why can't I inherit from ScrollChangedEventArgs?

Tags: c#

I have this

```
public class MyScrollChangedEventArgs : ScrollChangedEventArgs
{



}
```

and the compiler throws this error

> The type 'System.Windows.Controls.ScrollChangedEventArgs' has no constructors defined

EDIT: I should add that I looked at other similar questions which suggest that it happens when trying to access an internal constructor. The ScrollChangedEventArgs doesn't have an internal constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958358/the-type-has-no-constructors-defined

Comment: I edited the question to add that I've seen that answer and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @robola "The ScrollChangedEventArgs doesn't have an internal constructor" - [yes it does](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ScrollChangedEventArgs.cs).  It's just not documented on MSDN.

Comment: Why do you want to inherit from it?  Could you wrap it instead?

Comment: look [here](http://www.rvenables.com/2009/08/instantiating-classes-with-internal-constructors/).  Guy shows how to instantiate the class, but not inherit from it.

Comment: @DStanley - I am wrapping it now. I just wanted to know why I wasn't able to do it.